# WPF StackPanel controls order

Tags: wpf, stackpanel

Is there a way to change the order of the controls inside a StackPanel at runtime?

Many thanks,
Paulo

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
stackPanel1.Children.Remove(item);
stackPanel1.Children.Insert(newIndex, item);
```