# Swap position of two Canvas in a StackPanel

Tags: c#, wpf

So basically I have a simple `StackPanel` that contains multiple `Canvas`.
I want to swap the position of two `Canvas` in this `StackPanel` in Code. Pretty much like this:

```
<StackPanel>
    <Canvas Name="canvas1">
    </Canvas>

    <Canvas Name="canvas2">
    </Canvas>

    <Canvas Name="canvas3">
    </Canvas>
</StackPanel>
```

Whats the easiest way to swap canvas1 with canvas2 in C#?

Comment: does it have to be a StackPanel? can't you use a grid? maybe you can use a variable for the column / row and then swap those.
If not, I think that you can get a reference of the StackPanel, get a reference of its child elements and then change their positions

Comment: Possible duplicate of [WPF StackPanel controls order](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1398548/wpf-stackpanel-controls-order)

Answer (score 1):

You could remove it and insert it at another position within the `Children` collection of the `StackPanel`:

```
stackPanel.Children.RemoveAt(0);
stackPanel.Children.Insert(1, canvas1);
```

---

```
<StackPanel x:Name="stackPanel">...
```

Comment: Documentation sais to use [InternalChildren](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.panel.internalchildren(v=vs.110).aspx) for Panel derived classes. Same [UIElementCollection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.uielementcollection(v=vs.110).aspx) that supports Remove/Instert/InsertAt - Methods.

Comment: InternalChildren is internal. Children is public.

Comment: Ok, so it's only available if you yourself override Panel. Thanks, missed that.